# How to configure network connections between computers for Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure

Tags: ubuntu, networking, configuration, cloud

With the release of Ubuntu 12.04 I thought I'd try my luck with a private home cloud, I've been reading everything I could find but I've got some questions. I'm thinking of a pretty simple setup of 1 controller and 3 nodes. I know I need 2 NICs on each computer but I can't understand how to connect them all together. I've understood that you connect one NIC from each computer(nodes and controller) on a switch which only connects these together and the second NIC on each computer with a second switch that is also connected on the internet via router. Is that right?

I know my descriptions are somewhat lacking and at times quite confusing so I've made a schematic of how I've understood the process: 
http://biglle.com/node.jpg

And one final question, does the controller also act as a DHCP server for the whole network(there are other computers connected in the same network)?

If there is any info missing please let me know and I'll update this post.
Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
I had something like the setup shown in this tutorial in mind:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure

Comment: "Cloud" is a vague marketing term, but you're configuring more of a cluster than a cloud. Clouds usually refer to virtualizing systems. To make a home cloud, you can set up a hypervisor, configure 2+ VM's, and voila'...makin' it rain.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for clearing that out. If it is of any help I had something like the setup in this tutorial in mind, minus the part that says "minimum of 10 machines":
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure

I didn't post my question in the ubuntu ask section because I thought I was a more general question, I hope it is ok.

Comment: "Private home" and "cloud" are an oxymoron.

Comment: I only said "home" because that's where I want to deploy it for testing purposes. I don't understand why it would be an oxymoron, could you please explain?

Comment: I think Womble (and most of us) missed that you're talking about an actual product with "Cloud" in the name. Mostly because you didn't include the actual name of the product in your question, just as a reference to the help documentation in a comment below your question

Comment: I'll edit the question to add the link, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I may attempt at defining cloud from a pseudo-technical perspective: "A massively scalable computing system providing computing power, networking and storage facilities mostly using consolidated virtual computing methodologies to provide on-demand services, resource pooling and fast provisioning (elasticity)."

Aha. Anyone else, to improve!

Based on this your "cloud" may be exactly what your graphic says but that is not the only way. For example: why do you need a second private switch? To consolidate storage? Or are you looking to do a cluster? As indicated above even one server with two VM's is a way into the cloud. It is scalable - you can add systems and VM's ad nauseum. The rest - controllers, management nodes clusterizing, parallelizing etc etc - are entirely optional which extend your capabilities.

Comment: I was reading through the openstack docs and I read I needed 2 NICs per node and seeing the graphic below I thought that was what I needed to do. I'm just not sure if that is what they meant. I think a cluster would be a better idea because I've got quite a lot of computers sitting in the basement doing nothing and I could use them to see how/if this configuration works before buying any expensive equipment.

Graphic:http://bit.ly/IxfUG8 (First pic)

Comment: If I can clarify the second graphic a bit. That is a two-tier approach ie. the front row is the VM compute nodes (this is what the user sees usually), the second row, "back-end", are usually invisible to the users doing their special chores ex. storage, database servers, network controllers, monitoring and other functions for cloud maintenance/admin.

Comment: So, in essence, the second row is not really a requirement, is it?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Especially in the first stages of a large deployment or prototype. At least this is how I approach deployments: get the basics going the rest will follow - if you have a need.